# How can I get number from String with endWith function effectively and with clear code?

Tags: java, string, ends-with

I have inputs like "Test1","Test2"... and I just try to find end number in these strings. I wrote below code but I don't like it. How can I improve this code? Is there any advice?

```
 private int getEndNumber(final String str) {
    if (str.endsWith("1")) {
      return 1;
    } else if (str.endsWith("2")) {
      return 2;
    } else if (str.endsWith("3")) {
      return 3;
    } else if (str.endsWith("4")) {
      return 4;
    } else if (str.endsWith("5")) {
      return 5;
    } else if (str.endsWith("6")) {
      return 6;
    } else if (str.endsWith("7")) {
      return 7;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can the number be more than one digit?

Comment: Yes, numbers can be more than one digit.

Comment: Why is `8` and `9` missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is your friend.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+$"); // This regex matches the last number
Matcher m = p.matcher(str); // Create the matcher

//If the pattern matches then we get the matching string
if(m.find()) { 
    result = m.group();
}
```

You can alternatively iterate the string in reverse and check if the characters are integers, but that's rather tedious than using regexes.

There's a nice article about regexes here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

You read it thoroughly and forget everything in a few days, like the most of us :-).

Comment: Instead of [0-9] you can also just use \\d :)

Comment: @N4zroth Yeah, but I figured OP would read 0-9 easier than \d because he's apparently new to regexes

Answer (score 3):

One liner - return last character:

```
return Integer.parseInt(str.substring(str.length() - 1)));
```

If you want to return 0 also when ends with `8` or `9` you will need to add a bit logic to it

Answer (score 0):

Extension from @user7294900 but multi-liner.
In case you do not want to use regex.

```
    private int getEndNumber(final String str) {
        Integer num = 0;
        try {
            num =  Integer.parseInt(str.substring(str.length() - 1)) ; 
            num = num >= 7 ? 0 : num;
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            num = 0;
        }
        return num;
    }
```